# Explicit conversion and templated conversion operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I wanted to somehow extend the Microsoft type `_variant_t` so it accepts implicit/explicit conversions to/from additional types. To do so, I wrote the following class:

```
class value_type
{
  public:
    /* Constructors */
    value_type(const std::string& str) : m_variant(str.c_str()) {}
    template <typename Type> value_type(const Type& value) : m_variant(value) {}

    /* Conversion operators */
    operator const _variant_t&() const { return m_variant; }
    operator std::string() const { return static_cast<const char*>(m_variant); }
    template <typename Type> operator Type() const { return static_cast<Type>(m_variant); }
  private:
    _variant_t m_variant;
};
```

That is, if every instance of `_variant_t` in the code is replaced with `value_type`, it *"works"* the same.

Lets consider the following function, which returns a `_variant_t`:

```
_variant_t foo();
```

If I write:

```
std::string bar()
{
  value_type v = foo();
  return v;
}
```

It compiles just fine.

But if I change the previous code like that:

```
std::string bar()
{
  return value_type(foo());
}
```

or:

```
std::string bar()
{
  return static_cast<std::string>(value_type(foo()));
}
```

The compilation fails with the following message:

> configuration.cpp(41) : error C2668: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

If I remove the `template <typename Type> operator Type...` line, everything compiles.

Now I understand what the compilater says (it doesn't know which operator to use) but I don't understand why: It would seem logical to use the `operator std::string` when converting to `std::string`. What am I missing ?

Thank you.

Comment: According to my (limited) understanding of some paragraphs of the standard (13.3.3.1 and 14.5.5.2 mainly), I would say that your code is correct, but I may have overlooked something. Have you tried specializing the template conversion operator instead of overloading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that string's constructor is overloaded. So if returning involves invoking a string constructor, then there are multiple choices: argument could be converted to `const char*`, `allocator<char>` or `string`.

`static_cast<string>(x)` is the same as `string(x)`.

I suppose your first faulty example should read `return string(foo());`, not `return value_type(foo());`

Comment: I guess you are right about the "why". But I can't write `std::string(foo())` since there is no overload for `std::string::string()` that takes a `_variant_t` as it's first argument.

Comment: I meant that `return value_type(foo());` seems to be OK (with g++).

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not a typo. I'm using VC10 and it fails there.