# templated operator string() won't compile when temp object

Tags: c++, string, templates, operators, temporary-objects

Does anyone know why the last line in main fails to compile (note it is compilation that fails):

```
template <typename TT> inline TT getAs();
template <>            string getAs() { return "bye"; }
template <>            int getAs() { return 123; }

class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename TT>
        inline operator TT() const { return ::getAs<TT>(); }
    template <typename TT>
        inline string getAs() const { return ::getAs<TT>(); }
};

Foo tempFoo() { return Foo(); }

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    string testStringLocal = foo;       // OK
    int testIntTemp = tempFoo();        // OK
    string testStringTemp = tempFoo().getAs<string>();  // OK
    const string& testStringTemp2 = tempFoo();  // OK

    string testStringTemp3 = tempFoo(); //.getAs<string>();  // FAIL!
}
```

As I indicated by the comments for main's lines,

- the implicit conversion from Foo to string compiles fine on a non-temp object (such as foo),
- as well as on a temp object when converting to int (or long etc)
- it does work fine when converting to string via a method
- as well as if type is `const string&` instead of string

Tried this on VS2010. Note the above code compiles fine in 2005 but I believe 2010 is right.

Implicit conversion to string via operator works fine if I remove the template definition and specializations and simply define each overload explicitly:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    operator string() const { return ::getAs<string>(); }
    operator int()    const { return ::getAs<int>(); }
    ...
};
```

I'd prefer not to use this workaround as it is less maintainable.

Does anyone know of another way to have the last line of main() succesfully compile? I don't think the accepted answer to [Explicit conversion and templated conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079749/explicit-conversion-and-templated-conversion-operator) applies here, because there are multiple conversions possible (char *, alloc, string) regardless of whether templates are involved, and the fact the object is a temporary seems to matter.

EDIT: **Original code in this post showed some in-class template specialization, this was an artefact of creating a standalone piece of code for SO from my original source (I moved some namespace-level specializations into class and VS2010 did not complain). The issue is *not* specialization. I modified the posted code to be closer to original (as I just did), doesn't use in-class specialization (problem still there of course). Derek's answer indicates it might be specific to VS2010.**

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about Visual C++ 2010 (version 9.0 I think), but you can't specialize a templated member function in the class itself. It must done at namespace scope, according to the errors emitted by more modern compilers I gave this code to.

So,

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename TT> inline operator TT()     const;
    template <typename TT> inline TT       getAs()  const;
};

template <>  inline Foo::operator string() const { return "hi"; }
template <>  inline Foo::operator int()    const { return 123; }
template <>  inline string Foo::getAs()  const { return "bye"; }

Foo tempFoo() { return Foo(); }

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    string testStringLocal = foo;       // OK
    int testIntTemp = tempFoo();        // OK
    string testStringTemp = tempFoo().getAs<string>();  // OK

    string testStringTemp2 = tempFoo();  // OK!
}
```

Compiles fine with Visual C++ 12.0 and g++ 4.7.2.

Comment: Thanks but it is definitely not due to specialization: my application source code does not involve specializations in class, I put those in when creating standalone example (I don't know why VS 2010 did not complain). I have edited accordingly. But the code you show indicates perhaps it is a 2010 issue, I will see if I can reproduce in VS2012 express with my edited code.

Comment: Does not work in 2012 either, so unfortunately this answer does not indirectly address the issue (as per edited post) either. I have created a new question.